# How do I declare an array of unknown size then take input till I desire and then get the size of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I'm trying to declare an array of size 10,000. 
Preferably a character array. Then I may take the input of any size n(<=10,100). And I want to find this n.

I have a code which is not working.

```
int main()
{
    char arr[10000];
    cin >> arr;
    cin.sync();
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; ; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=='\n')
            break;
        l++;
    }
    cout << l;
    return 0;
```

Input : Hell
I expect the output to be 4, but the actual output is 4482.

Comment: You use `std::vector`. [VLA:s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) are not allowed in standard C++

Comment: Since `std::cin` stops reading on encountering the first ***whitespace*** `arr` will ***never*** contain a `'\n'`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `char arr[10000];` isn't a VLA (it's just a plain old array declared with an integer constant)

Comment: Consider using a `std::string` and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, but OP's question is about how to create a VLA. The code doesn't reflect it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin >> arr;` puts a C-style string into `arr`, which is terminated with `'\0'`, not with `'\n'` (even though you press enter to send the input to your program). To get that expected output of `4`, you need to change this

```
if (arr[i] == '\n')
```

To this:

```
if (arr[i] == '\0')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in standard C++. But you can use

```
std::vector<char> arr;
```

and `arr.resize(/*ToDo - size here*/)` when you need to. The `std::vector` memory management is also superior to using a large fixed-size array with automatic storage duration.

That said, a `std::string` is probably the best choice in your case:

```
std::string the_standard_library_is_fantastic;
std::cin >> the_standard_library_is_fantastic;
```

followed by

```
std::cout << the_standard_library_is_fantastic;
```

Your assumption that `arr` is in a sense terminated with a `'\n'` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard C++ library normally. `#include <string>` does this task easily.

```
string arr;
cin >> arr;
cin.sync();
int l = arr.length();
cout << l;
return 0;
```